# Understanding Performance & Diagnostic Tools In Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have just started to use the performance and diagnostic tools in Visual Studio 2013. I have been looking to tweak my C# applications as some of them are maxing out my CPU at run time. However, after running for instance the CPU profiler, I am no further forward as I am struggling to understand what it means.

Is there any good resource for explanations on cpu profiling, Instrumentation, .Net memory allocation etc.

**Here is one of the latest CPU sampling test**
[image]

Some instant questions I have from this is what is

- Inclusive Samples(%)
- Exclusive Samples(%)
- Wall Clock Time (Seconds)

Also,

Where do I start, how do I drill down into the application and target the issues.

Comment: a .ToList() call causes most CPU usage. Also opening the ODBC connection causes CPU usage. check your code for both issues